# Handsontable context menu paste not working first time

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Context menu works only after ctrl+v is used. Otherwise it just returns empty clipboard which makes me think that some init is needed or just focus/ select on textarea. Am I missing something? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Copying from excel file and pasting to Handsontable grid. If I will paste with ctrl+V everything is ok. After that both pasting with shortcuts and through context menu works as expected. But if after initialization I will try to use my contex menu paste it will paste nothing. Until I paste through shortcuts.

**EDIT 2**
http://jsfiddle.net/sauliuslx/ygfnR/341/
If you copy from excel smth like that
[image: copying from excel]

and paste to handsontable with ctrl+v then you'll be able paste with context menu too. On console you'll see

[image]

But then if you restart and try to paste with context menu it will paste nothing and on console you'll see

[image]

i.e. one element instead of four and value to paste is "". And so the difference is that you did not used shortcut. So these prepared smth?

```
attached(element) {
    this._grid = this.initializeGrid($(element).find(".inputGrid")[0], this.options);
}

private initializeGrid(element, options) {
    var config: any = {
        data: options.data(),
        colHeaders: options.columns.map(c => c['title'] || c.data),
        columns: options.columns,
        contextMenu: {
            items: { "copy": { name: "copy Ctrl+C" }, "paste": { name: "paste Ctrl+V" }, "hsep1": "---------", "row_above": {}, "row_below": {}, "remove_row": {} }
        },
        contextMenuCopyPaste: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        rowHeaders: true,
        allowInsertColumn: false,
        allowInvalid: false,
        allowRemoveColumn: false,
        manualRowMove: true,
        autoWrapRow: true,
        fillHandle: false,
        stretchH: 'all',
        height: '100%'
    };

    var grid = new Handsontable(element, config);

    var subscrRefresh = options.data.subscribe(() => {
        grid.updateSettings({});
        grid.render();
    });
```

Comment: Could you show us some code? Copy what from where?

Comment: @ZekeDroid I added initialization code. Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to recreate it. Could you post a jsfiddle where the error happens? Are you by any chance using IE?

Comment: @ZekeDroid I added jsfiddle. And I use Chrome 46. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing are the external files to `ZeroClipboard`. Simply download them and set them. Here's the direct text from the docs:

> Please note, that our Copy/Paste Context Menu plugin requires some additional preparation:
>
> 1. `ZeroClipboard.js` must be present on your server and included in your website's `script` tag.
> 2. `ZeroClipboard.swf` must also be present at your server
>      To configure Handsontable to use this plugin you need to add a `contextMenuCopyPaste` config item to your Hansontable instance.
>
> It can be set to:
>
> - `true` - if the `ZeroClipboard.swf` file is placed in the same directory as the `ZeroClipboard.js`, or
> - `{swfPath: [path to the swf file]}`

Comment: @ZakeDroid Thanks for your answer. And it seems all logical. I tryed this solution on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ygfnR/345/ . Because swf restrictions on framed sites like jsfiddle it will not work I tried it like that. http://jsfiddle.net/sauliuslx/k9psq1da/117/show/
http://jsfiddle.net/sauliuslx/k9psq1da/117
And it probably should work. But it does not. I also tried it on my site but I did not succeed either.

Comment: mmm that's strange then. at this point you should file it as a bug in the github issues page since it doesn't make any sense. You may still be getting the path wrong or not loading zeroclipboard correctly.

Comment: I see both of those files (js and swf ) on chrome debugger Network. And there is no errors. I guess chrome may be suppressing the flash. But yes it strange I found no complaints about that.

Comment: And I just tried to copy with context menu from grid to same grid. That works without issues from the start.